# Permutations with special restrictions and combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many permutations are there for $10$ football games were every game could be either $H, V$ or $T$ (which means that either the home team wins, the visitor team wins or tie accordingly)? The games are distinct and from that I assume that the order matters and thus we talk about permutations.

Now let's put the restriction of $4$ games being $T$ and $4$ games being $V$. How many cases are there?

Please note that the games are distinct and thus it is different for the first $4$ games to come a tie from the last $4$ games to come a tie.

What I have thought is:

The number of cases of $4$ games being tied out of $10$ is $P(10,4)$ and then there are $6$ games left so the number of cases for $4$ games being $V$ out of $6$ is $P(6,4)$. Finally the last 2 games can have either one of the three outcomes so this is $3^2$. The final result is their product:

$P(10,4)*P(6,4)*3^2=5040*360*9 = 16329600$ cases.

Is my solution correct or am I missing something? These seem like a lot of cases.

Comment: How have you defined P?

Comment: It's the universal symbol for permutations. $P(n,r) = \frac{n!}{{(n-r)}!}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the confusion in the question, I am adding both cases.

**Case1 :** When the outcomes of $10$ games are at least $4V$ **and** $4T$ which means other two games can have any of $3$ possible outcomes $(H, V, T)$.

Possible outcomes in this case -

$\{4V, 4T, 2H\}, \{6V, 4T\}, \{4V, 6T\}, \{5V, 5T\}, \{5V,4T,1H\}, \{4V,5T,1H\}$

So total permutations $ = 10! (\frac{1}{4!4!2!} + \frac{2}{6!4!} + \frac{1}{5!5!} + \frac{2}{5!4!1!}) = 6342$

**Case 2:** Outcomes are exactly 4 wins for V and 4 wins for T (so outcome of other two have to be $H$).

Just take the first term of the above $\{4V, 4T, 2H\}$ and that gives you $3150$ permutations.

Comment: You *thought* the same thing that I did - (instead) OP intended **exactly** 4V's and **exactly** 4 T's.  To avoid confusing OP, perhaps you can insert an edit explaining when your original answer is appropriate, and what the appropriate computation is under his *intended* interpretation.

Comment: OK I will do an edit. Based on how he went about, I thought he wanted to say last two games could be any outcome.

Comment: Yes, I had that reaction as well, looking at the 1st answer.  This triggered back and forth comments that I subsequently deleted.

Comment: @MathLover You are right. It's my fault that I created confusion. I think my case was to have **at least* $4V$ and $4T$, but I again that's me to blame. I accept your answers for answering both cases eitherway. I will fix my question asap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ instead of $P$.

For $2$ games with $3$ outcomes it would be $3^2$ and not $2^3$, but, as discussed in the comments, the last two games are home wins.

So, $\binom{10}{6}\binom{6}{4}=210\cdot15=3,150$.

Comment: How does this, take into condsidaration the order of the outcomes? Isn't that something like, if I have $4$ ties, 4 $V$'s and $2$ whatevers on whichever occasion this counts only once? I want for the $4$ ties to count differently, every time they happen in different $4$ games out of $10$. Sorry for the $2^3$ error, just fixed it.

Comment: @user2661923 I want exactly $4$ ties and $4 V$'s

Comment: If you want **exactly** 4 of each of V and T, you will have **exactly** 2 H, so you don't need $3^2$ at all.

Comment: @johngonidelis If you want exactly 4 ties, then you have to ask how many ways of selecting them are there, from 10 games.  Pascal's triangle kicks in.  The easiest way to *stretch* your intuition is to pretend that you want 4 games out of 5, then 4 games out of 6, ... and convince yourself that the computation is $\displaystyle \binom{\text{# of games}}{4}.$

Comment: @JMP while this answer is correct but your previous answer was not. If last two games could be any of the $3$ outcomes, your calculation showed 28k+.

Comment: @MathLover; I couldn't see where the $P$ came from!

Comment: @JMP Apologies. Thank you very much for clarifiying that to me. My question was wrong in the first place. I will fix it ;). Thanks for the clarification.